# How to export SQL Server 2005 tables to SQL Server Compact database 

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-ce

I don't know if this is a newbie question or not, I want to export some tables from "full" SQL Server 2005 database to a SQL Server Compact Edition database through a CLR stored procedure.

I know it is possible through SSIS.

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Compact Sql data will present at client machine with Master tables. When any user update the records in any master table, SQL Server will export that table data to shared CE db and application will download it to get updated information.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2012/02/migrating-databases-between-sql-server.html) shows how to migrate between sql server and sql server compact using [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/). so you can use the sql server compact script generated from your database to create [CLR stored procdure](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37298/CLR-Stored-Procedure-and-Creating-It-Step-by-Step)